# When running "npm run dev" [webpack-cli] Error: Cannot find module 'vue/compiler-sfc' [Laravel with Vue.js]

Tags: vue.js, webpack, laravel-8, npm-install, laravel-mix

after I installed vue.js on my laravel project and running `npm run dev` this error comes out.

[image]

Comment: just do an `npm install @vue/compiler-sfc`. More info here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@vue/compiler-sfc

Comment: @doesnotmatter Not if your vue version is 3

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I was having the same problem, basically what was happening is that my version of VUE did not match the version of vue-loader and vue-template-compiler

To solve it I just had to match the versions in package.json and `npm install`
here are the versions I'm using

```
"vue": "^2.6.11",
"vue-loader": "^15.9.6",
"vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.12",
"laravel-mix": "^6.0.6",
```

Comment: This work with me in laravel 8 the problem was from vue-loader version it was version 17.0.0 i changed it to 15.9.6 thanks Boutghat.

Comment: This worked for me as well. I think this issue occurs basically on MacBook. When using Windows PC, everything works fine with `"vue-loader": "^17.0.0"`.

Comment: I don't think it has anything to do with the OS !! the issue occurred to me in both windows and linux

Answer (score 2):

My issue arose after running `php artisan ui vue --auth`. What happened is that this command added vue v2 as a dev dependency in my `package.json`, while I had already installed vue 3.
Running npm install installed the version 2 vue, which led to a version mismatch with `vue-loader` and `vue-template-compiler`.

I solved the issue by getting rid of the added vue 2 dependency, and running npm install again.

Comment: Need to get rid of both of these: `        "vue": "^2.6.12",
        "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.12"
`